# Wordpress site will only load in Safari

Tags: php, wordpress, server

I have a weird problem that just started happening today on a Wordpress site I manage.

Everything loads find and works great on desktop Safari, and iOS Safari & iOS Chrome.

But when I try to load in desktop Firefox or Chrome, it's just a blank site.  No content is loaded at all.  It's not a problem with the domain — I can access individual image/text files through the browser, but my main Wordpress content won't load.

I tried updating all my plugins and my core Wordpress to 4.8, but still no dice.  I tried de-activating all my plugins and still the same result.

My server logs just show this for the blank loads:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated it!  Site is [spiltink.net](http://www.spiltink.net).

Comment: Not sure if you're using AWS, but [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613452/nginx-issues-http-499-error-after-60-seconds-despite-config-php-and-aws) might help

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using AWS and don't have a load balancer.  It's really weird, on anything but safari I get the 499 error right away — it doesn't spin for 60 secs before it times out.

Also, it ONLY happens on this website.  I'm hosting a bunch of sites on this same server, and all the others work just fine.  And I can access certain individual files on this site, but when I try to hit the actual full wordpress site, that's when I get the 499 error.