# NGINX/WP/PHP-FPM Burst of 499 Responses cause max_children issue

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Looking for helping investigating and isolating, TIA

*Please let me know if you need additional info (like config values)*

Every couple of days from a (known to be good) IP address flood my server (a very specific WP homepage), all with a response code of 499.

The access logs look like they are coming from Chrome and are coming in at like 6 per second until my `max_children` limit is hit after which I have to restart PHP-FPM. Then it's quiet for a long time until it happens again.

The PHP error logs do not show anything. It's actually empty for a good amount of time before and during this (which is odd).

I do see something on my monitoring service that's MySQL related, only by the time it occurred against the burst, but I'm not sure it's related as a cause or symptom or would cause a 499 response code:

`E_WARNING: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=2990`

```
in mysqli_query called at /wp-includes/wp-db.php (1931)
…pdb::_do_query called at /wp-includes/
wp-db.php (1820)
in wpdb::query called at /wp-includes/wp-db.php (2420)
…wpdb::get_row called at /wp-includes/
option.php (98)
…/wp-content/plugins/wp-user-avatar/includes/
wpua-globals.php (45)
…ww/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-user-avatar/
wp-user-avatar.php (77)
…ww/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-user-avatar/
wp-user-avatar.php (33)
…ww/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-user-avatar/
wp-user-avatar.php (97)
in include_once called at /wp-settings.php (305)
in require_once called at /wp-config.php (119)
in require_once called at /wp-load.php (37)
in require_once called at /wp-blog-header.php (13)
in require called at /index.php (17)
```

I'm at a loss for finding this :(

Comment: Maybe related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613452/nginx-issues-http-499-error-after-60-seconds-despite-config-php-and-aws

Comment: @YuJiaao Thank you. I am not using a load balancer and the burst of requests gives me pause his solution would work for me. Worth a shot and open to other solutions.