# nginx http 499 status code with AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

From time to time I am getting 499 status codes in the nginx logs of my web/app server (AWS linux AMI + nginx + php).

After reading [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613452/nginx-issues-http-499-error-after-60-seconds-despite-config-php-and-aws), I increased the ALB idle timeout from 60 secs to 300 secs.

The problem is still happening and I still can see the 499 errors.

The average latency in the AWS console (ALBs -> Monitoring -> Avg. Latency) is increasing at the time of the 499´s, which is causing the requests to take longer than expecting, and therefore those 499´s happen.

The other problem is that the ALB Healtch Check is also getting a 499 when the problem happens, and that is causing that the ASG to terminate and create new EC2s.

The strange thing is that I am getting the 499´s at the same time in three different environments, that are in 3 different custom VPCs and that are not sharing anything besides the AWS AMI (different RDS, ALB, VPC, EFS...)

I checked several issues from different people in the AWS forums related to this problem:

- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=576653&#576653
  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=287149&#287149
  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=297948&#297948
  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=791292&#791292
  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=291981&#291981
  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=651803&#651803

How to solve this issue?

Comment: I also want to know...Did you have any change resolving this issue?